# org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible

Tags: websphere, rmi, lotus-notes, corba, iiop

I am using Lotus Notes API (NCSOW.jar) to connect to a remote Domino server from my java class and then write to the Lotus Notes database. But I am getting a particular error which suggests that it might not be able to connect to it.

This is the line which cause that error. The URL is the Domino server name, and username, password as the domino server credentials.
Session session = NotesFactory.createSession(props.getProperty("LotusNotes.URL"), props.getProperty("LotusNotes.UID"), props.getProperty("LotusNotes.PWD"));

I am able to connect through this from my local machine with a standalone java program. But from a particular websphere server(v6.1)on our QA machines, this error comes up. We tried to check the ports, firewall and all is good on that side. We are able to connect from that server machine to the remote Domino Server machine properly.

The following is the stacktrace of the error.

org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible:
Forwarded IOR failed with: ORB_CONNECT_ERROR (5) - couldn't get Server Subcontract:org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4 vmcid: 0x49421000 minor code: 56 completed: No
Initial IOR failed with: ORB_CONNECT_ERROR (5) - couldn't get Server Subcontract:org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4 vmcid: 0x49421000 minor code: 56 completed: No vmcid: IBM minor code: E07 completed: No

```
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1177)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1260)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1349)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1128)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1315)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1861)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1271)
at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:460)
at lotus.domino.corba._IObjectServerStub.createSession(_IObjectServerStub.java)
at lotus.domino.cso.Session.OREFtoSession(Session.java:829)
at lotus.domino.cso.Session.<init>(Session.java:72)
at lotus.domino.cso.Session.createSession(Session.java:40)
at lotus.domino.NotesFactory.createSession(NotesFactory.java:67)
at com.my.apps.useraccessreview.EmpInfoMapper.buildMap(EmpInfoMapper.java:89)
at com.my.apps.useraccessreview.EmpInfoMapper.getInstance(EmpInfoMapper.java:40)
at com.my.apps.useraccessreview.InitializeEmpInfoMapper.run(InitializeEmpInfoMapper.java:36)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:571)
```

Does anyone has any suggestions on this.

Thanks
Mrutyunjay

Comment: I am not versed in Domino, but is there some kind of access rights list on the domino server, that says which user can log into server from which machine (IP)? The stack you provided seems like server tries verify user in some way in order to create session, and fails at that.

Comment: Davorin, I tried checking with the Notes Domino Adminstrator but do not find any ip specific blocking. I am in fact able to connect with the same credentials from my local java client that I used to test. The issue comes up when the same credentials are being used to connect from a web application deployed on WebSphere v6.1

Comment: Can you move your laptop to the same network segment as a WebSphere server for the purpose of testing?

Comment: Are you sure the context you are running in on Websphere is allowed to open network connections?

Comment: I have found the solution for this issue. The IBM documentation for the CORBA error "CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED" pointed to check the Websphere's FFDC log. On checking that I found that the global security was turned ON in that JVM. The ports for these 3 parameters were configured on the JVM:  SAS_SSL_SERVERAUTH_LISTENER_ADDRESS
CSIV2_SSL_MUTUALAUTH_LISTENER_ADDRESS
CSIV2_SSL_SERVERAUTH_LISTENER_ADDRESS . These 3 ports are relevant to global security and it must be turned OFF. On making these ports as 0 for that JVM in the WebSphere console, application was able to connect to Notes perfectly.